# Python MySql and variables in query

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

What is the trick to update two fields "wybor", "odebrano" using variables in Python

```
csv_data = csv.reader(file('tmp/orders.csv'))
for field in csv_data:
    id = field[0]
    data = field[1]
    login = field[2]
    wybor = field[3]
    godzina = field[4]
    odebrano = field[5]
    mysql.execute('INSERT INTO orders(id, data, login, wybor, godzina, odebrano) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLIKATE KEY UPDATE wybor = VALUES(%s), odebrano = VALUES(%s)', [id, data, login, wybor, godzina, odebrano])
```

> Error : 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Comment: Remove `VALUES(%s)` and replace with just `%s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably should be `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, not `ON DUPLIKATE KEY`. Also, I don't think you need (or want) the `VALUES` keyword in the `UPDATE` clause.

```
INSERT INTO orders
    (id, data, login, wybor, godzina, odebrano)
  VALUES
    (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    wybor = %s, odebrano = %s
```

Comment: Simply perfect!
I was working on it for few hours ;) thanks a lot